# How to filter list with objects in C#?

Tags: c#, list, filter

I have a class `House`, and I create a `List<House>`with some new Houses. Now I would like to filter my `List' where the Name of the House equals`"House 1"`.

How should I handle this situation?

I tried `houses.FindAll("House 1");` but this showed the error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to System.Predicate <"App.Page1.House">

```
class House
    {
        public House(string name, string location)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Location = location;
        }

        public string Name { private set; get; }
        public string Location { private set; get; }
    };

    //TODO: fill this with data from the database
    List<House> houses= new List<House>
    {
        new House("House 1", "Location 1"),
        new House("House 2", "Location 4"),
        new House("House 3", "Location 3"),
        new House("House 4", "Location 2")
    };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you have to give `FindAll` a predicate.  You can do that with a lambda

```
List<House> houseOnes = houses.FindAll(house => house.Name == "House 1");
```

Basically you have to tell it what you want to compare to for each item.  In this case you compare the `Name` property to the `string` value you are interested in.

Another alternative is to use Linq

```
List<House> houseOnes = houses.Where(house => house.Name == "House 1").ToList();
```

Note here you have to call `ToList` in order to get a list.  Without that you'd have an `IEnumerabl<House>` and it wouldn't actually do the comparisons until you iterated it (which the `ToList` does).  This is known as deferred execution and if your original `houses` list changed before you iterated it you could get different result, which may or may not be desirable.  By calling `ToList` you ensure that your results will reflect the state of your list when you make that call.

Answer (score 3):

Use Linq:

```
List<House> houseOnes = houses.Where(house => house.Name == "House 1").ToList();
```

or if there is only 1 you hope to find

```
House houseOne = houses.SingleOrDefault(house => house.Name == "House 1");
```

and check the result for null to make sure you found it.

Comment: Actually if you **are expeting only one** entity, you should use `houses.Single(expr)`. Otherwise, getting a `null` value will not be what you expected.

Comment: This has the benefit that it works against `IEnumerable<T>` not just `List<T>`, but differs slightly in that it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` with deferred execution on iteration, instead of a `List<T>` fully populated with the results of the find. Just highlighting the quite different behaviours of each.

Comment: @MatiasCicero I would say if you are expecting *exactly* one use `Single`, if you are expecting *at most* one, use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Couldn't have said it better myself

Answer (score 0):

U need to use the lambda expression to get it done.
`List<House> houseOnes = houses.Where(house => house.Name == "House 1").ToList();`

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but someone already gave this answer.